# Iterate files in git pages

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

On git pages, I have my index.html and besides it I have a folder with some text files, would it be possible to iterate those files in a JS function in the html file and how?

Comment: Why would you want to iterate through those JS files? Anyway, JS is not able to read directory structures from the file system for security reasons.

Comment: The files are located in the git repo and they are not JS but txt files. i don't want to mess with servers, hence I wanted to store some small data in them and consume it in the html.

Comment: You can use JS to retrieve them in an AJAX call, but you will need to know the individual URL of the text files. Unless you have a server side script (since you're hosting on GitHub pages, I guess not), there's no way to do directory scanning/file globbing.

Comment: @checho, are you talking about GitHub Pages website?

Comment: @VictorYarema yes

Answer (score 0):

You should know that you can use [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/) logic when publishing on github pages.

This can help you loop over posts, pages or collection items, and print everything in html, json, or watever you want.

Comment: And how exactly jekyll can help when you have only files in dir and some javascript that needs to get a list of those files?

Answer (score -1):

GitHub pages doesn't have a dir listing feature. If you need to know the list of files then you need to keep a dedicated file for that. It is obvious that you'll have to update that file to reflect the actual set of files in mentioned dir.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?